# Winforms Application Setup Creation in VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I know that this is a very stupid question, but I have not been able to find a definitive Guide to creating a basic Installer for my windows forms application. I know we have to use Setup and Deployment Projects in VS2010 but have not been able to find any step by step guide for it.

If possible please guide me regarding the same.
Thanks

Comment: There's a wizard built into Visual Studio that will walk you through creating the setup project. That's not enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

Many Winforms projects don't require an installer.  Just copy the files in the Release folder, formally named "XCopy deployment".  The walkthrough for a Setup and Deployment project [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently learning how to do setup projects as well.. I found a couple of sites that helped me to get off the ground and have a basic installer. I know the first link is from way back in 2005, but it still helped.

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/dcc5ab62-b875-4852-9e34-8bc2794e4fb8/c--create-setup-project.aspx